# Replace WooCommerce product price with a text for unlogged users and a specific product Tag

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

In WooCommerce, I use the following code:

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_tag' );
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($terms); $i++) {
    $tags[] = $terms[$i]->slug;
    }
    ?>
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <?php if (is_user_logged_in() && in_array('HIDDEN TAG', $tags)): ?>
        <span class="price">Please Log-in</span>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

On products, this code should replace price by **"Please Log-in"** when customer is not logged on products that have 'HIDDEN TAG' product tag.

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be `! is_user_logged_in()`. I have shorten and revisited your code:

```
<?php global $product;

// To be sure that we get the product Object (if needed)
if( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') )
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );

if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) { 
    // Get the term ID from 'HIDDEN TAG' product tag
    $term_id = get_term_by( 'name', 'HIDDEN TAG', 'product_tag' )->term_id;
    // added "!" to is_user_logged_in() for unlogged users and made some other changes
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && in_array( $term_id, $product->get_tag_ids() ) ) { 
        echo '<span class="price">'.__("Please Log-in").'</span>';
    } else {
        echo '<span class="price">'.$price_html.'</span>';
    } 
} ?>
```

It should work now.

> **The code could be even shorter**, if you can set directly in the code the correct term ID for 'HIDDEN TAG' *(instead of the term name)*, like for example *(if* `57` *is the term Id)* in:
>
> ```
> in_array( 57, $product->get_tag_ids() )
> ```
>
> Removing unneeded:
>
> ```
> // Get the term ID from 'HIDDEN TAG' product tag
> $term_id = get_term_by( 'name', 'HIDDEN TAG', 'product_tag' )->term_id;
> ```